# ActiveRecord query returns different results for two in-memory instances of the same database object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a console session, repeatably, If I access a certain model instance by pulling out of an array, I get incorrect results when calling a method on that object. However, if I load the same object directly from the database with `find(id)`, the same method returns the correct results.

How can this happen? The *really* crazy part is that for the first two elements of the array, everything is normal. As you can see at the end of the console output, results for the first two elements in the array (they are all the same type and all have two `Link` children) make sense. The latter five should not be empty.

```
# Instance from an array
irb(main):417:0> the_array = User.find(89).utterances.select{|u| u.links.count > 1}
=> [#<Utterance id: ...>, #<Utterance id: 6931, ...>, #<Utterance id: 6935, ...>, #<Utterance id: 6944, ...>, #<Utterance id: 6955, ...>, #<Utterance id: 6989, ...>, #<Utterance id: 7014, ...>]

irb(main):418:0> from_array = the_array.last
=> #<Utterance id: 7014, ...>

irb(main):419:0> from_array.class
=> Utterance(id: integer, index: integer, begins_at: float, text: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, ends_at: float, recording_id: integer)

irb(main):420:0> from_array.links.class
=> Link::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

irb(main):421:0> from_array.links
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

# Instance from find
irb(main):422:0> from_find = Utterance.find(7014)
  Utterance Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "utterances".* FROM "utterances" WHERE "utterances"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7014], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Utterance id: 7014, ...>

irb(main):423:0> from_find.class
=> Utterance(id: integer, index: integer, begins_at: float, text: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, ends_at: float, recording_id: integer)

irb(main):424:0> from_find.links.class
=> Link::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

irb(main):424:0> ap from_find.links
[
    [0] #<Link:0x000055fc7f154150> {
                  :id => 212,
                  #...
    },
    [1] #<Link:0x000055fc7f15feb0> {
                  :id => 213,
                  #...
    }
]
irb(main):425:0>

# But for the first two elements of the array, no problem
irb(main):486:0> the_array.each{|u| puts ap u.links}
[
    [0] #<Link:0x000055fc80cc34e0> {
                  :id => 208,
                  ...
    },
    [1] #<Link:0x000055fc80cc3328> {
                  :id => 209,
                  ...
    }
]

[
    [0] #<Link:0x000055fc80cc7180> {
                  :id => 211,
                  ...
    },
    [1] #<Link:0x000055fc80cc6fc8> {
                  :id => 210,
                  ...
    }
]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]
```

Comment: `u.links.count` does not load the associated links. It runs a `select count(*)`.

Comment: @Schern Correct, and I'm using its return value as an integer.

Comment: What is `ap`? And can you show us the User, Utterance and Link models. Just their association definitions. Also try `from_array.links.to_a` to force the CollectionProxy to resolve.

Comment: Hi @Schwern. All good questions. `ap` is a call to awesome_print, a pretty printing library for Ruby.

An  `Utterance` `has_many` links.

Good idea regarding the casting, but it hadn't made a difference. I'm confident that my answer below is correct given that the same expressions were entered right before and after quitting the first console session.

Answer (score 0):

[Associations are cached](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching). `from_array.links` is getting the cached set from when it was first called, `from_find.links` is getting a fresh copy from the database. Presumably some links were added between the first call to `from_array.links` and `from_find.links`.

If you run [`from_array.links.reload`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-reload) it will refresh the cached association and you should get the same result as `from_find.links`.

---

You can avoid stale association caches by [altering the association using methods on the collection](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference). For example, if you want to create a new link...

```
# This will update the utterance.links cache
utterance.links.create!( some: "attribute" )

# This will not.
link = Links.create!(
  some: "attribute",
  utterance: utterance
)

# This will.
utterance.links << link

# This will not.
link.destroy

# This will.
utterance.links.destroy(link)
```

---

Note that: `User.find(89).utterances.select{|u| u.links.count > 1}` is inefficient. It must load each Utterance and count its links individually, known as an N+1 query (or 1+N).

It's more efficient to do this with a join and a group by.

```
User.find(89).utterances
  .joins(:links)
  .group('utterances.id')
  .having('count(utterances.id) > 1')
```

Comment: "Presumably some links were added between the first call to from_array.links and from_find.links." This is not the case. As you can see, these are consecutive console statements, and the app is not in production (no one is using it).

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be that my console session was somehow corrupt. I took the following steps and then all of the calls to the `links` mtehod on the `Utterance` model, from the array, worked as expected.

1. Quit the console
2. rails c
3. Paste this code:

   ```
   the_array = Recording.find(89).utterances.select{|u| u.links.count > 1}
   from_array = the_array.last
   from_array.class
   from_array.links.class
   from_array.links
   from_find = Utterance.find(7014)
   ap from_find.id
   ap from_find.class
   from_find.links.class
   ap from_db.links
   the_array.each{|u| puts ap u.links}
   ```

Step 3 is the same thing I was doing in the previous console session. Apparently I had somehow borked the previous session's stack.

Comment: [awesome_print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) hasn't been updated in years. Consider [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) and [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug).

Comment: awesome_print is not a debugging tool for Rails, it's a pretty-printer for Ruby. It merely reformats Ruby's output to stdout for the sake or readability. It seems likely that Ruby's default `to_s` method for an `Object` hasn't changed in the last couple of years. What's to update?

Comment: You might be right, but `pry` has pretty print built in and specific rails console integration. It's a very good replacement for irb. I've never heard of the rails console being borked like that. I still suspect what happened is the CollectionProxy did not need to perform the query until something expanded it.